# How can PNG image transparency be preserved when using PHP code for Thumbnail Generation

Tags: php, thumbnails

I am trying to preserve the transparency of PNG or GIF images but with my code of generating thumbnails, I am getting black background of images instead of transparent.

Here is my code :

```
function create_image($source_image_path, $thumbnail_image_path, $real_width, $real_height,$source_image_height,$source_image_width)
{
   list($source_image_width, $source_image_height, $source_image_type) =     getimagesize($source_image_path);
$source_gd_image = false;
switch ($source_image_type) {
    case IMAGETYPE_GIF:
        $source_gd_image = imagecreatefromgif($source_image_path);
        break;
    case IMAGETYPE_JPEG:
        $source_gd_image = imagecreatefromjpeg($source_image_path);
        break;
    case IMAGETYPE_PNG:
        $source_gd_image = imagecreatefrompng($source_image_path);
        break;
}
if ($source_gd_image === false) {
    return false;
}


$thumbnail_gd_image = imagecreatetruecolor($real_width, $real_height);
if(($source_image_type == 1) || ($source_image_type==3)){
    imagealphablending($thumbnail_gd_image, false);
    imagesavealpha($thumbnail_gd_image, true);
    $transparent = imagecolorallocatealpha($thumbnail_gd_image, 255, 255, 255, 127);
    imagefilledrectangle($thumbnail_gd_image, 0, 0, $real_width, $real_height, $transparent);
}

imagecopyresampled($thumbnail_gd_image, $source_gd_image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $real_width, $real_height, $source_image_width, $source_image_height);
imagejpeg($thumbnail_gd_image, $thumbnail_image_path, 100);
imagedestroy($source_gd_image);
imagedestroy($thumbnail_gd_image);
return true;
}
```

With the above code I'm getting black background of image.

I tried using  `imagecolorallocate($thumbnail_gd_image, 255, 255, 255);`. But with this  `imagefilledrectangle()` give me white background.

Can anyone help me to get the transparent background for PNG or GIF images?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is in the line below:

```
$thumbnail_gd_image = imagecreatetruecolor($real_width, $real_height);
```

According to http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatetruecolor.php

> imagecreatetruecolor() returns an image identifier representing a black image of the specified size.

Comment: Could you please tell me what should i do to fix it??

Comment: I would start by reviewing the comments from the PHP.net manual link I provided, creating a test of the process, and evaluating where the errors occur. That said, I have very little experience with PHP image manipulation, but based on your code, I could consider replacing $thumbnail_gd_image  with $source_gd_image for the first bit. Honestly, read the manual user comments. The very first one is how to have a truly Transparent PNG

Comment: On comparison, have you tried changing $transparent = imagecolorallocatealpha($thumbnail_gd_image, 255, 255, 255, 127); to 0,0,0, 127?

Comment: I got the fix... I checked a condition that the image is JPG or PNG OR GIF, if it is PNG then imagepng($thumbnail_gd_image, $thumbnail_image_path, 9 ); will work which gives me transparent image background.. I just want to know that imagepng($thumbnail_gd_image, $thumbnail_image_path, 9 ); will work both for GIF and PNG images??